# Angular8 UI page is not working after saving the child component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have created angular8 project and added a child component "main-nav" and added as a attribute in app.component.html. When ever if i did some changes in child component and click on save, child component related UI is not working with CSS. Every time i am stopping the terminal and doing ng serve then UI is working fine.
I am new to angular. Please help me in resolving the issue.

My output is like this
    [output][1]
If i save my changes then getting output like this
    [error output][2]

Here is my code

```
app.component.html
-----------------
<main-nav>
  <button>test</button>
</main-nav>

app.component.ts
----------------
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(){}
}

app.module.ts
------------------
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MainNavComponent } from './main-nav/main-nav.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainNavComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }

main-nav.component.html
-----------------------
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" 
  >
<mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
<mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item href="#">Main</a>
  <a mat-list-item href="#">Banking</a>
  <a mat-list-item href="#">Reporting</a>
</mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <button
    type="button"
    aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
    mat-icon-button
    (click)="drawer.toggle()"
    >
    <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <span>Application</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

main-nav.component.ts
-----------------------
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'main-nav',
  templateUrl: './main-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-nav.component.scss']
    })
export class MainNavComponent implements OnInit{

      constructor() { }

             ngOnInit() {
          }
        }

      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzD3t.png
      [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ked7w.png})
```

Comment: please update your question again